What is the end-game of Canada's accusation against the Indian government?

Canada–India diplomatic row

There has been a diplomatic standoff going on between India and Canada for some time now regarding the assassination of Canadian national Hardeep Singh Nijjar by some Indians.
Even if the Indian government approved that assassination, what is Canada going to achieve by continuing with this standoff given that India has much stronger political and economic clout than that of Canada?

The presumption that a country has an "end game" in foreign policy matters is doubtful. Politics is more like tennis than chess.

That one is easier to guess:
Cease and desist from targeting Sikh residents on Canadian soil, if they were indeed doing it.  Remember that the US has also raised similar concerns so Canada is not as isolated as all that.
New Zealand is a minnow relative to France, yet the latter had to eat crow after they got caught out during the Rainbow Warrior affair.
I would go as far as adding that a deal might also, and constructively so, get Canada to police some of the activities Sikh separatist activists are up to on Canadian soil.  Some of it has been rather nasty, like the Air India bombing whose prosecution was botched.
I like Sikhs well enough, but the minority of violent activists for Khalistan, should not be allowed to use Canada as home base for terror acts abroad.
However, killings on Canadian soil by foreign powers, be they India, is just not acceptable.  (Or harassment of our citizens by China, for that matter).
